# How to hide cursor blinker (caret) in wysiwyg editors on demand? (redactor.js)

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, redactor

I'm trying to hide the blinking caret when clicking on certain elements in wysiwyg editors (in my case redactor.js) but I suppose all are the same.

I don't want to disable the whole input area, it just hide the caret and not allow any input when clicking certain elements.

Comment: use a custom cursor png for 100% invisibility. i use ":focus { cursor: crosshair;}" for less-obtrusive cursor on photos...

Answer (score 4):

You can set caret position when clicking certain elements.

*Set cursor position to a specific position of an element :*

```
$('#redactor').redactor('setCaret', element, 4);
```

*Set cursor to the end of an element :*

```
$('#redactor').redactor('selectionEnd', element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `contenteditable=false` attribute on elements that should not be editable.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    editable part
    <span contenteditable="false">read only part</span>
    editable part
</div>
```

See a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ebhxy/

However, as everything related to `contenteditable` - if editor which you use does not have support for nested non-editable elements,the UX will be poor and very buggy.

Comment: unfortunately it's just a html5 feature :)

Comment: What is an HTML5's feature? Contenteditable? It's supported since IE5.5. Without it WYSIWYG editors would not exist.

Comment: You're right. Anyway, it doesn't solve the problem inside the editor. Thank you!